# Can I use JavaScript objects passed to Rust to implement structures that need garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, rust

When using Rust in a browser, I can get JavaScript objects and use them inside Rust (using, for instance, the `js!` macro from the [stdweb library](https://github.com/koute/stdweb)).

Given that these objects came from JavaScript, can I use them in Rust to implement structures that benefit from garbage collection (for instance, to implement graphs)?

Comment: Graphs don't need garbage collection, FWIW, depending on your meaning of "garbage collection". Rust does not have a garbage collector, yet still has graphs.

Comment: Graphs are only an example of a data structure that can benefit from using a gc.

Comment: There's a difference between "structures that **need** garbage collection" and "structure that can **benefit** from". You stated *need* and I'm pointing out that's not correct.

Comment: I guess you would need to write the code for the graph in JS, as you cannot instantiate the JS objects from Rust (or can you?)

Comment: It's possible to use the `js!` macro and initialize the JS objects from Rust.

Comment: I have two concerns: how the the gc in JS deals with objects that it passes to Rust and possible delays when accessing JS objects in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on cost of JS<>Wasm interaction, and the way you're going to use the data.

To get definitive answer you'd have to try a specific algorithm and benchmark it, but in general I don't expect it to be beneficial.

For complex object graphs in Rust you'd use `Rc<RefCell<…>>`. It has a relatively low overhead, so you'd need to have very GC-friendly usage pattern to beat it, especially given overhead of JS objects.

Comment: What about the JS reclaiming memory of an object it passed to Rust. Can this happen?